# Best stats test to use for right and left handed bias?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, spss

I an new to stats! I need to analyse left and right handed bias. So my data shows 66.9% of right hand use (in overall tasks) and 33.1% of left hand use in one set of subjects (study set 1) and 45.3% right hand use and 54.7% left hand use in second set of subjects (study set 2). For the write up I need to include statistical analysis - e.g. is this statistically significant in either set - looks like maybe so in set 1 and not so in set 2... Yet I don't know how to do this! I have access to SPSS. Can anyone please advise me?

Comment: Before asking if there is statistical significance, you must first clarify the question you are asking. It seems that you want to know if there is a difference between the two sets of subjects. Please provide more information about the data so others might assist you.

Comment: I am asking if baboons use their right hand more than thier left during feeding in set one and if red tail monkeys use their right hand more than their left hand in feeding in set two. I wish to know if there is a statistical significance between hand use for each species. (not a comparison) just is is statistically significant that for example baboons use their right hand more for feeding.

Comment: You cannot ask if something is "statistically significant" without providing something to compare.  Please, in extreme detail, state the research question you are attempting to answer.

Comment: Is it not comparing to look at of a monkey uses its right hand more than its left? I have data from monkeys that show for example they use their right hand more times than their left but don't know which test to use to get a statistics answer....

Comment: This is my data.Table 1. Baboons hand usage.
         RH LH 
Feeding 98 68 
Foraging 22 14 
Grooming  0 0 
Scratching 42 52 
Table 2. Red-tailed guenons hand usage
         RH LH 
Feeding 57 78 
Foraging 10 8 
Grooming 1 0 
Scratching 8 0
Wipe face 5 4

Comment: My questions are simple. Do baboons use their right hand more than their left hand? AND Do red tailed monkeys use their right hand more than their left hand? (for the tasks I was collecting data for - no need to break them down either)

Comment: Is it possible for them to use both hands at the same time?  How would that be coded because it would change the type of statistical test?  If it is forced to be either left or right, then the binomial would work, but not if they have an option of using both hands.

Comment: I did get data for both hands at the same time but I wish to look at if there is a right hand bias. Thus have excluded activities where they used both hands at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

For a problem like this, the basic comparison being assessed is if the probability is statistically different from 50%. Using the NHST notation
$$H_0: \pi = 0.5$$
where $\pi$ is the probability of using right hand (works the same if you set it to left hand usage).

The most straightforward test to use here would be a test using the normal approximation. First, we get the proportion using right hand, $p = \frac{98}{98+68} = \frac{98}{166}=0.5904$. Now we compare this to chance for a distribution that has $\pi=0.5$, which would have a mean proportion of $0.5$ and a standard deviation of $\sqrt{\frac{0.5·(1-0.5)}{166}}=0.0388$. Calculating a $z$-score:
$$z = \frac{0.5904-0.5}{0.0388}=2.328$$
Now, you can calculate the probability of observing a $z$-score of this magnitude (or larger) using the standard normal distribution.  In this case, the $P$-value is $p=0.0199$.

This test can be applied to every pair of RH/LH data set collected (as long as there are 5 or more for each observation). Note, this does not allow for direct comparison of handedness for one activity vs another, or different rates of handedness between species. That would require a different test.

Hope this helps.

**Addendum #1 (for SPSS)**
Open SPSS, and then open a new Syntax window.  Cut and paste the following code and run.

```
DATA LIST LIST
 / rhVSlh freq .
BEGIN DATA.
0 98
1 68
END DATA.

WEIGHT BY freq.
NPAR TESTS
  /BINOMIAL (0.50)=rhVSlh.
WEIGHT OFF.
```

The data is entered as 0 & 1 for RH and LH, respectively. The frequency for each is the 2nd column of numbers.

Comment: Thank you. Thus I can use this to just find out over all the activites if there is a right or left hand dominance correct? I do not need to separate the activities at this point.

Comment: How do you calculate the standard normal distribution please?How do you go from the z value to find the p value?

Comment: ¿What statistical software package will you be using?

Comment: I have access to SPSS